# Tensorflow Endless eval

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Its stucks in batch[0].eval(). Any idea why and how to fix it?image_paths,lbl are tensors with len 1.

It is based on https://gist.github.com/eerwitt/518b0c9564e500b4b50f example on reading mutiple jpg images, but i want to swap from tensor []..[]..[] to 3 different tensors.

Code:

```
image_paths,lbl,num_img = read_label_file(filedir+LABEL_SCP,filedir) 

image_paths = tf.train.string_input_producer(image_paths, shuffle=False)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(image_paths)
img = tf.image.decode_image(value)

img, c,h,w = getCHW(img)

min_queue_examples = 10000
batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img,lbl],
              batch_size=batchSize,
              num_threads=1,
              capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batchSize,
              min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples,
              enqueue_many = False,allow_smaller_final_batch=True)    
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer() #   ----Begin fix
with tf.Session() as sess:                  #
    sess.run(init_op)                       #
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()          #
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) #End fix
    batch[0].eval()
    batch[1].eval()    
    sess.run([batch[0], batch[1]])
    coord.request_stop()          #   Begin Fix
    coord.join(threads)           #
    sess.close()                  #   End Fix
return batch,num_img,c,h,w
```

Comment: Does it get stuck too if you do `batch.eval()` instead?

Comment: batch itself is a list of 2 tensors so i cant use .eval() on it

Comment: with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
    
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) 
        shape = tf.shape(batch[0])
        assert(int(sess.run(shape[0]))==batchSize)
        assert(int(sess.run(shape[1]))==h)
        assert(int(sess.run(shape[2]))==w)
        assert(int(sess.run(shape[3]))==c)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()   

works fine, but eval() still doesnt work

Comment: **please** add that to the question as edit, this is unreadable.

Comment: Also, you have no coordinator or `start_queue_runner` calls in your original code. Unless you add that, eval won't work because the queues it's trying to get data from are not being populated (although it should raise an error and not freeze in that case I think)